# Swift appendContentsOf (order)

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

when I use:

```
  func addResults(){
    let myUniqueResult: [[String]] = []
    //some work
    var myResults = [[String]]()
    //some work
    myResults.appendContentsOf(myUniqueResult)
}
```

The entry order for results is maintained?

Thanks

Comment: is this a question "The entry order for results is maintained?" it seems more like a statement. What are you trying to figure out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since arrays are ordered collection types, **yes it is**.

Prove it by pasting this in a playground

```
for _ in 0..<10000 {

  var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  let b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

  a.appendContentsOf(b)

  if a != [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] { fatalError("Wrong Order") }
}
```